# How to get the input value on Formtastic's hint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I have a Formtastic form and would like it to display a link in the hint if there's one.

```
f.input :link, hint: 'link here'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found to solve this was to use `f.object`and then call the attribute `link` on it, like so:

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :link, hint: link_to(f.object.link, f.object.link)
    end
    f.actions do
      f.action :submit
    end
  end
```